# Gitlab-ci allow manual continuation if coverage job fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline that checks test coverage on the master branch against the current branch to make sure it hasn't decreased. If the test coverage fails, I would like to be able to manually continue the pipeline (it has to be manual so there is acknowledgment that the coverage has decreased).

According to the Gitlab-ci documentation, there is no current ability to start a job both `when: manual` and `when: on_failure`. It would be possible if I had an additional manual override job, and could specify an `OR` on the `needs` property of the following job or something similar. So far I have not been able to find a solution like that. Is there a workaround I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and wanted to say: No, its not possible, but then came up with an idea - I dont have time to test it right now, but just to give you an idea.

You could use a variable that you define at the beginning like

```
variables:
  SUCCEDED: false
```

And then set it in your first job in the script method to true AFTER the unit test is running, like:

```
jobUnitTest:
  script:
    - Command for your unit test here
    - export SUCCEDED=true
```

And then run the next step on manuel AND when the variable is false, like this:

```
jobGoOnManuel:
    when: manuel
    only:
      variables:
        - $SUCCEDED == false
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try this method and the problem is, a variable set inside a job does not change the global variable, so the next job does not have the context of the changed boolean. I also tried using a file artifact to export the env variables, but the artifact isn't read until the job has already started.

Comment: Right. I founs the same idea here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/25919
The idea they have is have a file in which a var is saved, change the filecontent in Job 1 and read it in job 2. Because the source in your working directory is copied every time you start a job, you should transfer the information between jobs then.